# JS based analytics

Tags: php, javascript, analytics, bots

Scenario -> Website which uses javascript to track users. This is for traffic analysis.

Problem -> Some people posting the data using bots and curl in php.

Wanted solution -> Only allow legitimate users statistics to be counted in the analysis.

Comment: Are you actually sure there is a problem? Bots and curl shouldn't parse the JavaScript, so they shouldn't be triggering a count.

Answer (score -1):

> Problem -> Some people posting the data using bots and curl in php.

cURL doesn't execute JavaScript, nor does it fetch image assets, so it won't be counted in analytics collected with either of those methods.

Comment: they post the data direct to the server

Comment: Which doesn't change my answer at all, since that was pretty clear from the original question.

Comment: C'mon mate, dont you get it! Javascript collects the analytics but where does all that collected data go!!!! The data is posted to a database! So there are some people who are doing that! I would like an answer about how to prevent that.

Comment: How are you determining that people are targeting your analytics JavaScripts for abuse? That's a pretty unusual situation.

Comment: That is not the question....You can create a new question if you want to ask that question, but if you cant answer my question, just dont start asking me irrelevant questions.

Comment: I am determining that by looking at the records where some ips are posting data such as screen sizes where they are changing them to their own desired sizes multiple times in one session

Comment: It is not irrelevant, I'm trying to fully understand your issue. I'm trying to understand why a bot would want to fake various screen size settings in a session, because it seems likely that something else is going on.

Comment: I think it is because they are changing it so often that my database is being populated with garbage. They might be my competitors but the main issue is that how do I prevent this from happening.